# Density of continuosly differentiable function in space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C([0,1])$ be the set of all real continuous functions with the standard supremum norm. Let $C^1([0,1])$ be the set of all real continuosly differentiable functions on $(0,1)$ such that the derivative can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$.

Is $C^1([0,1])$ a dense subset of $C([0,1])$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Although this might be overkill, this follows from Weierstrass' approximation theorem, because $\mathbb{P}([0,1])$ is a subset of $C^1([0,1])$. Here $\mathbb{P}([0,1])$ is the space of all polynomials on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Overkill indeed. But it works. Thanks!

Comment: For even more of an overkill, it suffices to use polynomials with rational coefficients and such that only prime powers of $x$ have a nonzero coefficient (see [Müntz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem)).